# Cannot see traces in AWS Xray

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops, aws-xray, opencensus

I'm trying to upload some traces on AWS xray using opencensus.
The route of traces is simply this:

`client -> opencensus agent -> xray`

I'm using a docker-compose.yml with this configuration:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  #login
  login:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: login
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
  #ocagent
  ocagent:
    image: omnition/opencensus-agent
    volumes:
      - ./ocagent-config.yaml:/conf/ocagent-config.yaml
  #xray
  xray:
    image: amazon/aws-xray-daemon
    volumes:
      - ./.aws/:/root/.aws/
    command: -o -n eu-west-1 --bind=xray:2000
```

and my config file for the opencensus exporter to aws is this:

```
exporters:
   aws-xray:
    region: "eu-west-1"
    version: "latest"
    buffer_size: 200
```

I uploaded credential as environment variables.

when I run `docker-compose up` my service starts and all works fine but the traces doesn't show up in the console, it seems traces get lost in the route (maybe for a misconfiguration).
Can you help me pls?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: yup, but the problem wasn't in the yaml but in the golang code, I had to add client.Do, to send the request, no traces were found because there effectively there was no trace